# Mystery of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+2\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}.$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+2\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}.$$
And the question is to prove that it has a local maximum in $0$. So the taylor polynomial is given by $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^4}{16}+o(x^4)$ as wolfram says (and confirm by the correction of my exercise): [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20((x%5E2%2Bsqrt(1%2Bx%5E2))%5E(1%2F3)%2F(2%2Bsin(x)*sin(x))))

But the graph is 
what show a minimum. So my question is: What's wrong ? I don't understand !! Why the graph gives a minimum and not a maximum ?

[image]

Comment: you simply haven't zoomed enough on $(0,1/2)$ to see the local maximum there.

Comment: The sure way is to compute the derivative $f'(x)$ and the second derivative $f''(x)$. Then if $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)<0$ you get a maximum and if $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)>0$ you get a minimum

Comment: I think the graph shows a maximum. Zoom in, look more carefully. Perhaps I am wrong, but this is a very likely explanation. What look like almost a horizontal line probably has a little hump, if you zoom in, and rescale appropriately, try it.

Comment: The graph has two minima near $x=\pm 0.9$ with the values of the function at these minima about $0.495$.

Comment: I see... indeed, if I pay more attention, I see it. Sorry for the disturbing... I was a little bit confused at the first looking.